# How to/ Where to delete/edit an index from MySql which prevents duplicates row

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm using SugarCRM and a few weeks ago I executed a a query on MySQL which created an index to prevent duplicate rows. Where can I see that or find it and edit or delete this ? I'm not able to remember the exact query but it's needed to add more columns. Using MySQL only just a few weeks.

> MySQL error 1062: Duplicate entry 'example-dyplicate' for key
>   'idx_name'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the structure of a table, including all the indexes, use:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;
```

You can delete an index with:

```
DROP INDEX indexname ON tablename;
```

There's no way to edit an index. If you want to change an index, you drop it and then add a new index with the new columns you want. However, you can do both in a single query using `ALTER TABLE`:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP INDEX indexname ADD INDEX indexname (col1, col2, ...);
```

Comment: I just figured it out before I read your answer. My solution was with MySql Workbench right click on the Database  -> inspect schema -> Indexes -> find the index name and which table on it and execute the mentioned DROP INDEX indexname ON tablename; query. Thx.

Comment: I don't use a GUI to interacti with MySQL, I just use the CLI.